# Generating dynamic size permutations in SWI-Prolog results with ERROR: Out of global stack

Tags: prolog, clpfd

I'm trying to generate multiple permutations using this code:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

p(N, Indexes) :-
    M in 1..N,
    M #=< N,
    length(Indexes, M),
    Indexes ins 1..N.
```

It returns me all the results, but in the end crashes with `ERROR: Out of global stack`

Comment: the condition 'M #=< N' is already implied by 'M in 1..N'

Comment: Yes, but using the trace i saw prolog is not ending the loop so i thought that this could help, but it didn't

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What happens in your code is that the length of the list is implicitly set by calling `length/2`. This will start with a list of length 0, which binds `M` to 0, which in turn wakes up the constraint `M in 1..N`, which fails. Next it returns a list of length 1, which succeeds, then on backtracking a list of length 2, which succeeds again. After that, any further backtracking into `length/2` will return longer and longer lists, but waking `M in 1..N` will always fail until the list becomes so large that you run out of memory.

What you need to do is place the choicepoint before the `length/2` call instead of inside of it by, e.g., replacing

```
M #=< N,
```

(which is a redundant constraint anyway) with

```
indomain(M),
```

This gives you:

```
[debug] [1]  ?- p(2,I).
I = [_G3025],
_G3025 in 1..2 ;
I = [_G3102, _G3105],
_G3102 in 1..2,
_G3105 in 1..2.

[debug] [1]  ?-
```

Comment: Thank you, it solved my problem, but I have trouble understanding why;) Dou you have any link to documentation why `M` becomes 0? I tried also ading `M #>=` which was also redundant and did not help. I thought that `M ins 1..N` is something like loop, but I assume it only becomes loop when we force it to be in the domain.

Comment: @Łukasz: M **starts** from 0, as twinterer clearly (thanks! +1) explained. Try this query: ?- length(X,Y).

Comment: @Łukasz: `M ins 1..N` is not a loop, it's a constraint that restricts the domain of `M` to be between 1 and N. As a constraint, it gets suspended until the bounds of `M` change, when it will be woken and check its consistency. `length/2` is *not* a constraint, i.e., the domain of variable `M` is not taken into account. Calling `length/2` with uninstantiated variables will have it return an empty list. This binds `M` to 0, which changes the bounds of `M`'s domain and thus wakes the constraint posted on `M`. The constraint then checks it's consistency and fails, since 0 is not in the domain.

Answer (score 3):

It is not clear to me what you mean by multiple permutations. But probably your program shall start with `between/3` and then contain an `all_different/1` constraint.

```
p(N, Indices) :-
    between(1,N,M), % or maybe rather between(0,N,M).
    length(Indices, M),
    Indices ins 1..N,
    all_different(Indices).
```

And then, use `labeling/2` to generate actual solutions.

Comment: +1 for better solution, not just fixing the bug. (should be `Indices ins 1..N` though)

Answer (score 1):

As twinterer already answered to question, I just add a simpler way to get (proper) permutations (could be useful?):

```
permutations_n(N, P) :-
  numlist(1, N, L),
  permutation(L, P).
```

test:

```
?- permutations_n(3, X).
X = [1, 2, 3] ;
X = [1, 3, 2] ;
X = [2, 1, 3] ;
X = [2, 3, 1] ;
X = [3, 1, 2] ;
X = [3, 2, 1] ;
```